# How to make renderPlot happend before another reactive depending on same input

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have one numericInput. The value of numericInput is plotted and put into reactive value. How to update the plot before updating another reactive value? Plot always goes gray until reactive value is updated.

Edit1: The code below is minimal fake example of my problem. I sometimes have a shiny app where a change in one input both triggers a plot and updates some reactive value. In example below, `input$i` is plotted and the value is put into reactive `value()`. `Sys.sleep(3)` demonstrates that if reactive calculation takes a long time, app first does that and then updates the plot. Sometimes it would be nice to first update the plot and then make the long calculation. My question is this; can I force `renderPlot` to happen first and then another reactive?

Example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("i",
               "i",
               value = 0),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = NULL, aes(x = input$i, y = input$i)) + geom_point()
  })

  value <- reactive({
    Sys.sleep(3)
    input$i
  })

  observe(print(value()))

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I don't really understand your problem and I don't understand the purpose of plotting a unique point, could you explain?

Comment: There is no point in plotting a unique point. It was just a demonstration that the plotting happens last and it waits for longer calculation (Sys.sleep(3)) to finish. I would like make plot happen first and other calculations later.

Comment: If I understand well, when you recalculate the plot (which takes quite a long time), you want to conserve the previous plot and show the new plot only when the calculations are over. I don't know how to do it, but I think that the user can get lost with that because if the plot does not change until the (long) calculations are over, he has no indications that he actually launched the calculations. I would recommend to you the use of [progress indicators](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html), which can show that there are calculations running but are better looking than a grey area

Comment: Realculating the plot does not take a long time, it is very quick. Recalculating another reactive value takes a long time. I would like to update the plot quickly and then calculate the time consuming reactive value. However, the time consuming reactive value is calculated first and then the plot (which takes very little time). I would like to reverse this order.